# Writing static utility class in Java EE system

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

I want to develop a utility class, that can be used in a static manner (static methods), for an enterprise Java system (JSP, Servlets, EJBs). It'd contain some methods that is capable to access the `HttpSession` object of the user and retrieves some useful info that is already stored as attributes (such as the current user id).

Some of you may wonder why do I need such thing, while I can simply passing the `HttpSession` object to anywhere. Actually, I am working on a legacy Java EE 5.0 system and some of the utility classes (not Servlets, JSPs, nor EJBs) have no access to the `HttpSession` object.

Is it possible to implement such utility class? Some constraints I/you should consider here:

- The servlets/JSPs are hosted on machines that are different from what host EJBs.
- The system is running on Weblogic 10.3.0.
- On weblogic, there are many servers (that host servlets/JSPs) and they are under the same cluster. The same thing is with EJBs servers.
- If I declare some static `Collection` inside the utility class, is it going to work? or maybe there will be more than one copy of it because of the multiple class loaders and multiple JVMs?
- Maybe I should use a shared file or shared database to implement it? How even could I track which user invokes the utility class? Maybe tracking the thread? or maybe something related to the transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). You should only not store the `HttpSession` directly in there. The service layer should not have any dependency on `javax.servlet` API. Instead, extract the desired information from the `HttpSession` directly and store it there.

E.g. when you want to expose `User` attribute of the `HttpSession` as a thread local variable:

```
public class SomeContext {

    private static ThreadLocal<SomeContext> instance = new ThreadLocal<SomeContext>();
    private User user;

    private SomeContext(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public static SomeContext getCurrentInstance() {
        return instance.get();
    }

    public static SomeContext newInstance(User user) {
        SomeContext someContext = new SomeContext(user);
        instance.set(someContext);
        return someContext;
    }

    public void release() {
        instance.remove();
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

}
```

and this in `doFilter()` of a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info):

```
User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
SomeContext someContext = SomeContext.newInstance(user);

try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} finally {
    // It's very important to do this in finally!
    // Threads are namely pooled by the container.
    someContext.release();
}
```

in any code which is running in the very same thread after the particular filter, including EJBs, you can get the `User` as follows:

```
User user = SomeContext.getCurrentInstance().getUser();
// ...
```

Comment: Maybe this is irrelevant, but I always wonder if the EJBs classes (.jar) within the same application are loaded with the same class loader or different class loaders? As I read somewhere, each .war is loaded with a different classloader. I am just concern of using static variables here.

Comment: JavaEE specification gives no guarantee, that an EJB-call will be processed within the same thread. It depends on the EJB-container implementation and I'm not sure, if you would get away with it using WebLogic. It should also be clear, that this will only work within the same JVM instance, so remote calls could get broken.

Comment: Eng: put the context and model in EAR. @Boris: the answer assumes a Java EE web application with `@Local` EJBs which are invoked on HTTP requests (which is all what the question is about). For `@Remote` EJBs, just use RMI interceptor instead of servlet filter. Alternatives are using `PolicyContext` or passing the desired `User` as method argument.

Answer (score 1):

The HttpSession is local to a Thread.

Do you really need an HttpSession or could you just do what you want with a static ThreadLocal attribute?

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

btw, Apache Shiro uses this class to store some "Session" information.

Comment: The HttpSession is not local to a thread. It's part of a Map with SessionID being the key. Any thread can access it if it has the sessionid or the HttpRequest object.

Comment: I think `ThreadLocal` would work if the user requests and transactions are always served by the same thread.